# Assigning custom file descriptors in bash and writing to it

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I was playing with bash a bit and was trying to assign a custom descriptor to a file to read from or write to.

Here is what i did:

```bash
exec 5> hello.txt    # assigned 5 to hello.txt

echo "hello brother" >& 5        # works
```

Now the thing that i am not understanding is that if i do this instead

```bash
echo "some text" > 5           # does not work, creates a file named '5'
```

It does not work like the above `>&`.

I understand:

1. `>&` redirects stdout & stderr
2. `>` redirects stdout

What is it that i am missing, is `>&` necessary when using descriptor?

Comment: @Ron I read that, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand:

This is exactly the problem - `>&5` is ambiguous. That's why you shouldn't use `>&` and prefer `> file 2>&1`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

There is a special logic, that if the next token after `&` is a digit, then it's redirection of stdout to a file descriptor `> &5`. https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/parse.y#L645